# Does Spring Data Validator has to be multi instance?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-validator

I have the following code for my Spring API validator.

```
@Component
public class EventValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clz) {
        return Event.class.equals(clz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I use autowire in my controller to add this validator into bindings as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/events")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @Autowired
    private EventValidator eventValidator;

    ...

    @InitBinder("event")
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(eventValidator);
    }

}
```

Is this correct? The reason I asked is that I see a lot of examples online are actually adding validators by new instance such as

```
@InitBinder("event")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(new EventValidator());
}
```

My questions are:

1) Can I use the autowiring way? If no, why do I have to get a new instance?

2) If we have to do a new instance, how can I autowire my repository interface in it for my validation? My repository is an interface extends from Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Why should a validator need to know about an HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you refer [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.context/3.2.5/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.java#DataBinder.addValidators%28org.springframework.validation.Validator%5B%5D%29), you will find that `addValidators()` method takes an array of validators and calls `assertValidators()` method which performs the NULL check and IllegalState exception check. After that is adds that validator array in the FINAL field validators which is of type List.

**So, answer to your first question is autowiring should work here. As creating new object everytime is not making any sense here.**

2. I hope the above answer solves this one too! If not then please comment on this answer, I will give it a try.